# Is type also object in Swift? and what's the meaning of sending a message to an object

Tags: swift, object, message

This might no be particularity a language related question. Since the Swift is the language I'm currently learning so I'm using it here.

I picked up this sentence from the Matt Neuburg's book ***iOS 10 Programming fundamentals with Swift***

```
In Swift, "everything is an object" and an object

Object is something you can send a message to.
```

Let's add an example. Suppose there is a customer type called **Dog**. It has **bark()** and **sit()** function. Two instances of the type **Dog** named **fido** and **rover** had been initiated.

```
In swift, the syntax of message-sending is dot-notating, like

fido.bark()
rover.sit()
rover.printName()

The above code lines means sending message to object fido and rover
```

**Question 1**:

Why the description is: Sending message to object **fido** and **rover**? To me it looks like the object **fido** and **rover** sends out some message to print it out in the console (ex. printName() ) rather we sending message to it. **.bark()** looks like it will make fido to do something and shoot its reaction to the outer world, because **bark()** is the function inside its belly, not something we created and inject in to its body. we just inform this function its the time to work. Is this informing object to do a specific thing is the meaning of sending the message to the object?

**Question 2**:

```
"In Swift, everything is an object", an object is something you can send message to
```

If I understand correctly, even the object type itself is also an object. such as **String**, **Int** or **Double**. Because type has type properties which means you could send a message to it

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: The "message" linguistics stem from comparing Swift to its closely related older sibling Objective-C, which does not directly easily translate to what we humans might refer to as a "message". I quote [programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html): _"Sending an Objective-C message is conceptually very much like calling a C function"_

Comment: @dfri So "Sending" a message here is roughly equal to "Calling"  a function in C content

Comment: For first question, you can understand simply: sending message to an object <==> calling a function off an object. It's an expression used by Apple in their documents on Objective-C.

Comment: @Hoa Thanks for your help

Comment: @Hoa, well actually they borrowed `sending message` expression from `Smalltalk`, one of the first OOP languages. Also ObjC bracket syntax is based on `Smalltalk` syntax too.

Comment: As to question 2, see [the following Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804349/what-is-an-object-in-objective-c), which describes it well: _"Message sending is performed as so: `[obj message]`. Essentially, an object in Obj-C is anything that responds to a message. This means that even classes are objects."_.

Comment: object type is not object. It's the definition of object. Object is an instance of a type. When you call a class function, the OS creates a class instance and call the function on that object (instance).

Comment: @Hoa In page 6 of the Matt's book, it says "For object-C, an object is a class or an instance of a class" I guess object type is also a class

Comment: I'm not agree with "an object is a class". object type is a class/truct. The fact that we call a function on class/struct (class function) does not mean class/struct is an object. See my comment above about calling class function.

Comment: @Hoa I agree that classes are not fully objects (and are implemented with different data structures), but this is incorrect: "When you call a class function, the OS creates a class instance and call the function on that object (instance)." That's not how either ObjC or Swift call class methods. They work directly with the class structure and do not instantiate an instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is some debate within the OOP world about "message passing" versus "method calling," both in how we talk about them, and how they're implemented. In the prototypical OOP language (SmallTalk, which ObjC is a descendent of), everything really is a "message." I bundle up a message (which is a real data structure, `NSInvocation` in its most heavyweight form in Cocoa), and deliver it to the object's inbox, which then processes the message and performs some action.

Most common OOP languages didn't adapt this model (when something does today, we tend to call it "actor" rather than "object"). C++, which heavily inspired most of the current crop of "object-oriented" languages took a "method calling" approach. This is much more closely aligned with function calling, and has to do with jumping to a specific point in memory and executing instructions there. Method calling is more static than message passing. It is much easier at runtime to completely reconfigure how messages are handled, create new message handlers, re-route old message handlers, etc. Method calling is much faster.

In practice, there isn't a huge difference in most programs at most call sites. The vast majority of ObjC "messages" translate precisely 1:1 into a method call, and the system almost always avoids generating a full `NSInvocation` message (they're insanely expensive).

But we still conceptually mix the two ideas when we teach OOP, and that's what's happening here. (Swift also happens to employ both mechanisms heavily.)

A good way to think of `fido.bark()` is "send the `bark` message, with no parameters to `fido`." It is then up to Fido to decide what to do about that. In practice, messages are usually understood to be "commands" in that the object doesn't "decide" what to do. But in principle it might. For example, Fido might be a pretty smart dog, and decide not to bark because it's so late at night, even though you told him to, or maybe he's asleep and he doesn't like to bark then. The concept of objects is that they encapsulate that knowledge and state.

To your second question, in Swift types are not full objects. They're "metaobjects." You are absolutely right that you can send messages to them, and so they in some ways behave like objects. But Swift doesn't have "first class types," which means that not everything you can do with an object can be done with a type. But yes, you're definitely on the right road that in many cases you can treat a type as if it were an object.

(A major Swift feature request is to make types more first-class by adding a concept called Higher Kinded types. This would make it possible to write methods on `Array` itself, rather than only on `Array<T>`, and make some types, like Functor, possible to write at all.)

Comment: Thanks so much for such clear and detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I was also reading a book < iOS 9 Programming Fundamentals with Swift >, there are some interesting aspects of looking at 'everything is object in swift'.

> "In Swift, everything is an object", an object is something you can send message to

In swift, we can add extension for String, Int, Double...etc

for example.

```
extension Int {
func sayHello() {
    print("Hello, I'm \(self)")
    }
}
1.sayHello() // outputs: "Hello, I'm 1"
```

The **1** here is not a class or instance, it is a struct. Swift has three kinds of object type: classes, structs, and enums.